# PHPUnit mock object methods

Tags: php, phpunit

I am learning unit testing with PHPUnit and am running into a strange problem with mock objects that I can't resolve.  I set up these dummy files as an example of what I am experiencing:

Class1

```
class PrimaryObj1
{
    function doNothing(SecondObj $s)
    {
    }
}
```

Class2

```
class PrimaryObj2
{
    function doNothing(SecondObj $s)
    {
        $s->TestMethod();
    }
}
```

and a test file as:

```
class PrimaryObj1_test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $primaryObj;
    function setUp()
    {
        $this->primaryObj = new PrimaryObj1();
    }
    function testDoNothing()
    {
        $secondObj = $this->getMock('SecondObj');
        $secondObj->expects($this->once())
                  ->method("TestMethod");
        $this->primaryObj->doNothing($secondObj);
    }
}
```

(one test file for each dummy class where everything is the same except for the class name).

When I run PHPUnit, this is what I get:

```
Running Tests/PrimaryObj1_test.php
1) PrimaryObj1_test::testDoNothing
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:TestMethod> when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

Running Tests/PrimaryObj2_test.php
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mock_SecondObj_99c898e7::TestMethod() in PrimaryObj2.php on line 5
```

So first it is mad that it didn't call the expected method but then when I do it gets mad cause it is undefined.  I just can't win.  I think this is why I'm still single...

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: Show code of `SecondObj`

Comment: SecondObj only exists as a Mock.  It has no code or class declaration

Comment: AFAIK the mocked class must exist

Answer (score 1):

I got a response from an email list serve with the answer.  This line:

```
    $secondObj = $this->getMock('SecondObj');
```

should be:

```
    $secondObj = $this->getMock('SecondObj', array('TestMethod'));
```

Once I made that change it worked as expected.